# Корректность модульного(MS Test, C#) теста

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, юнит-тесты, mstest

Подскажите где косяки в тестирующем методе.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetFigures), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void TestFigures(Shape shape)
{

    // .txt файл содержит фигуры с такими же характеристиками, как и в GetFigures()
    List<Shape> shapes = reader.ReadDataFromCSVFile(figuresFileDir);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, shapes);

    // Нужно найти в shapes все фигуры, равные shape
    // Equals перегружен сравнением площадей
    List<Shape> equalShapes = new List<Shape>();
    equalShapes.Add(shapes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Equals(shape)));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, equalShapes);
}

private static IEnumerable<Shape[]> GetFigures()
{
    yield return new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle("Rectangle", (8, 19), (16, 34), (46, 16), (38, 2)) };
    yield return new Triangle[] { new Triangle("Triangle", (15, 15), (47, 40), (65, 20)) };
    yield return new Square[] { new Square("Square", (6, 3), (6, 27), (30, 27), (30, 3)) };
}
```

Comment: а что этот метод тестирует?

Comment: @tym32167 работу метода _ReadDataFromCSVFile()_ и _Equals()_

Comment: 1) Юнит тест должен тестировать что то одно 2) я не вижу тут теста метода `ReadDataFromCSVFile`. Что конкретно вы в нем тестируете? Что у вас есть файлы в той папке? Что эти файлы в нужном формате? Что их там не один файл? А если файлов нет, вам что, null вернет, а не пустой список?

Comment: другими словами, в вашем тесте плохо все, начиная от названия теста (которое вообще бессмысленное и не говорит ничего о тесте) и заканчивая тем, что не ясно вы тут вообще тестируете.

Comment: @tym32167 вас понял, сейчас все исправлю.

Comment: Второй ассерт у вас совсем какой-то бесполезный. Он всегда будет `true`, независимо от того, что вернет `reader.ReadDataFromCSVFile`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, тоже уже заметил, сейчас все замечания аккумулирую и изменю.

Comment: Я бы, на вашем месте, подумал над самим методом `ReadDataFromCSVFile`. Почему он называется `ЧитаюДанныеИзФайла`, а принимает он на входе папку? В чем смысл тестирования того, что у вас данные в файлах не совпадают с данными из `GetFigures`? Если вы тестируете чтение (формат), я бы переделал метод на `ReadDataFromStream` и передавал бы `Stream` на вход, тогда вы можете подсталять нужные данные прямо в тесте (используя MemoryStream) и не тестировать стандатные библиотеки для чтения файлов. Плюсом ваш метод стал бы более гибким и не привязанным к файловой системе, мог бы читать по сети, например

Comment: @tym32167, неправильно дал название аргументу. У меня есть ```private readonly string figuresFileDir = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + @"\Resources\Figures.txt";```

Comment: Если вы тестируете Equals, то это абсолютно другой набор тестов, никак не связанный с `ReadDataFromCSVFile` или каким то списками или linq. Тестируете Equals - вызывайте только Equals в своем тесте.

Comment: ^ во певых, для этого есть `Path.Combine`, во вторых, как я уже сказал, вообще не ясно как этот код ^ относится к проверке чтения данных.

Comment: @tym32167, насчет изменения метода чтения  из файла. Вы что-то похожее имели в виду? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232443/writing-to-then-reading-from-a-memorystream

Comment: Я имел ввиду принимать не figuresFileDir, а Stream

Answer (score 0):

По понятным(уже) причинам, исправил тесты на следующий вид

```
private readonly FileReader reader = new FileReader();
private readonly string figuresFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName, "Resources", "Figures.txt");

[TestMethod]
public void ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile_ArgumentNullException()
{
    Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(() => reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(null));
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("")]
[DataRow("NonexistentPath")]
public void ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile_Exception(string pathToFile)
{
    Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(() => reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(pathToFile));
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile_PositiveTestResult()
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(figuresFilePath));
}

[TestMethod]
public void ParseCSVDataFromFile_PositiveTestResult() 
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(figuresFilePath));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, MyParser.ParseCSVDataFromFile(reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(figuresFilePath)));
}

[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(GetFigures), DynamicDataSourceType.Method)]
public void FindEqualShapes_PositiveTestResult(params Polygon[] shapes) 
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(figuresFilePath));

    List<Polygon> shapesFromFile = MyParser.ParseCSVDataFromFile(reader.ReadingCSVDataFromTextFile(figuresFilePath));
    Assert.AreNotEqual(null, shapesFromFile);

    List<Polygon> eqaulShapes = (from Polygon shape in shapes
                                    where shapesFromFile.Any(s => s.Equals(shape))
                                    select shapesFromFile.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Equals(shape))).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(eqaulShapes.Count != 0);
}

private static IEnumerable<Polygon[]> GetFigures()
{
    yield return new Rectangle[] {
        new Rectangle("Rectangle1", (8, 19), (16, 34), (46, 16), (38, 2)),
        new Rectangle("Rectangle2", (10, 20), (14, 38), (60, 19), (39, 4)),
        new Rectangle("Rectangle3", (11, 22), (15, 31), (51, 22), (30, 7))
    };
    yield return new Triangle[] {
        new Triangle("Triangle1", (15, 15), (47, 40), (65, 20)),
        new Triangle("Triangle2", (14, 17), (41, 52), (61, 19))
    };
    yield return new Square[] {
        new Square("Square", (6, 3), (6, 27), (30, 27), (30, 3)),
        new Square("Square", (7, 2), (5, 30), (31, 27), (30, 3))
    };
}
```

Comment: В вашем подходе все еще есть глобальный недостаток. У вас тест `TestFiguresEquality` по сути проверяет то, что в вашем тестовом файле лежит именно 3 прямоугольника, 2 треугольника и один Square. Это не очень полезный тест, потому что тест зависит от внешнего файла, который никак не синхронизирован с вашими ожидаемыми данными. Если вы все же хотите оставить метод  `ReadDataFromCSVFile` таким, какой он сейчас, и написать честные тесты, то вам прямо в тесте нужно создать CSV файл с этими фигурами, а уже потом прочитать его. Тогда сам тест будет отвечать за создание тестового файла для себя.

Comment: Ну, и желательно, чтобы тест чистил за собой созданные файлы

Comment: @AndreiKhotko может я криво написал, вернее свернул код, метод _FindEqualShapes_PositiveTestResult_ (бывший _TestFiguresEquality_) ищем среди фигур из файла и созданных мной(_GetFigures()_) равные. Исправил ответ. Получается так, что файл с фигурами есть только в пользовании у проекта тестов, нужно ли все равно его создавать принудительно, а не использовать готовый?